# ImageView как в xml установить отступ сверху?

Tags: xml, android, изображения

Я хочу, что бы имеющаяся картинка не была впритык к верхней границе экрана, а что бы был не большой отступ. Как это сделать?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/sovmestnajrabota" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_marginTop="Значение"`